# Moviepy zooming effects need tweaking

Tags: python, animation, video, moviepy

I would like to zoom a clip to a certain dimension, then stop further zooming. In other words, the clip stop further increasing its size after reaching a certain size, and its better if the clip start zooming from much smaller of its original size, and to a bigger version. I am using moviepy module. With the following code I can progressively zoom a clip, but having a hard time figuring out how to grow a clip from small to big, creating an animated effect. Any feedback you provide is greatly appreciated.

```
import os
from moviepy.editor import *

screensize = (640,360)

clip = (ImageClip(img)
        .resize(height=screensize[1]*4)
        .resize(lambda t : 1+0.02*t)
        .set_position(('center', 'center'))
        .set_duration(10)
        )
```

I am having a very hard time figuring out how to write a function in order to create a type-writing effect with moviepy's txtclip, meaning letters within the clip will be shown one after another, creating a smooth type-writer animation text. Moviepy got some helpful classes such as findObjects--which can detect individual letters out of a clip:

```
txtClip = TextClip('Cool effect',color='white', font="Amiri-Bold",
                   kerning = 5, fontsize=100)
cvc = CompositeVideoClip( [txtClip.set_pos('center')],
                        size=screensize, transparent=True)

letters = findObjects(cvc) # a list of ImageClips 

here is the link: http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/examples/moving_letters.html
```

after finding the letters(letter clips) I would like to join them in such a way that they appear one after another, which looks like type writing.

The documentation already got a few examples of moving letters, which might be of great use, however. Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a way of achieving what you want. The key is to define the resizing logic in a named function instead of using a `lambda`.

```
import os
from moviepy.editor import *


def resize_func(t):
    if t < 4:
        return 1 + 0.2*t  # Zoom-in.
    elif 4 <= t <= 6:
        return 1 + 0.2*4  # Stay.
    else: # 6 < t
        return 1 + 0.2*(duration-t)  # Zoom-out.

duration = 10
screensize = (640,360)

clip_img = (
    ImageClip('test.png')
    .resize(screensize)
    .resize(resize_func)
    .set_position(('center', 'center'))
    .set_duration(duration)
    .set_fps(25)
    )

clip = CompositeVideoClip([clip_img], size=screensize)
clip.write_videofile('test.mp4')
```

**EDIT**

The code that follows answers the second part of your question (I don't know if it'd be better to make two separate questions).

```
from __future__ import division
from moviepy.editor import *
from moviepy.video.tools.segmenting import findObjects


def clip_typewriter(text, duration_clip, duration_effect):
    # `duration_effect` is effectively the time where the last letter appears.
    clip_text = TextClip(
                    text,
                    color='white',
                    font='Consolas',
                    fontsize=80,
                    kerning=3,
                    )
    letters = findObjects(clip_text, preview=False)
    # Select the start time in seconds for each letter found:
    n = len(letters)
    times_start = [duration_effect*i/(n-1) for i in range(n)]
    clips_letters = []
    for i, letter in enumerate(letters):
        clips_letters.append(letter
            .set_position(letter.screenpos)
            .set_start(times_start[i])
            .set_end(duration_clip)
            # Here you can add key sounds using `set_audio`.
            )
    return CompositeVideoClip(clips_letters, size=clip_text.size)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    screensize = (320, 180)
    fps = 12
    clip_1 = clip_typewriter('hello', 2, 1).set_start(1).set_position('center')
    clip_2 = clip_typewriter('world', 2, 1).set_start(4).set_position('center')
    clip_final = CompositeVideoClip([clip_1, clip_2], size=screensize)
    clip_final.write_gif('test_typewriter.gif', fps=fps)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your code. It works as expected; I got just another problem with moviepy. Can I let you know?

Comment: I have updated my post with another problem. You can look at it. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, your logic is what I have been looking for. You does not seem to offer any links for future communication inside your account. How the future communication will be made? Any email id?

Comment: You can now find contact information in my profile. But please, if you have questions related to programming, publish them here at SO so anybody can benefit from the answers.

Comment: Yes, stackoverflow is the right platform. Just sent you a test email, however.

Comment: @feqwix Thanks for the zoom effect code even so many years later. But something to note. It may break the animation if the duration is much longer.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Zoom In and Out effect
def zoom_in_out(t):
    """Defines a zoom in and out function based on a sin wave"""
    return 1.3 + 0.3*np.sin(t/3)

clip.resize(zoom_in_out)
```

For anyone interested in making a periodic zoom in and out function.